# Best way to update custom structure using string member as index in C++

Tags: c++, containers

I have the following structure:

```
struct SensorData {
    std::string sensor_name;
    int state;
    int percentage;
};
```

I am receiving/updating this structure and would like to store it in an array/vector/list to keep track of the percentage value.

Everytime I receive a packet I should check for the name and update their fields.

Trying to figure a more efficient way to do this? Trying to avoid duplicate entries and use the "Sensor_name" member as an index.

Suggestions?

Comment: Perhaps use [`std::unordered_map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map)?

Comment: Use a `std::unordered_map<std::string,SensorData>` to do that.

Comment: *Everytime I receive a packet I should check for the name and update their fields.* -- Hopefully you are aware that in general, the data structure that is used for something like this is called a [hash table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table).  A hash table in C++ is spelled `std::unordered_map`.

Comment: Or do you maybe need to store more than one percentage value for each sensor?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest to separate the sensor name from the data and build two related structures (`SensorData` and `SensorInput`), one containing the other. The `std::map`<sup>[1]</sup> makes it easy to store and update the data via `string` key.

See the following example:

```
#include <map>

struct SensorData {
    int state;
    int percentage;
};
struct SensorInput {
    std::string name;
    SensorData data;
};

std::map<std::string, SensorData> g_sensor;

void update(const SensorInput& input) 
{
   g_sensor[input.name] = input.data;
}
```

... that includes a global variable and a plain function to keep it short.

---

<sup>[1]</sup>
The `std::map` template is the *traditional* implementation of an associative container in C++ that is already available in C++98, for more sophisticated, maybe more efficient solutions, see for the article [*Containers library*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) on cppreference.com!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It seems a straightforward implementation. My goal for having the map is to store/update sensor percentage values which will be going from 0 to 100. So i will be iterating the map until I can read 100 in all items.

Comment: For the iteration loop and accessing the percentage, should be:

map<string, SensorData>::iterator it;

for (it = g_sensor.begin(); it != g_sensor.end(); it++)
{
    std::cout << it->first    // string (key)
              << ':'
              << it->second.percentage   //<------???  
              << std::endl;
}

Comment: In that case, it would be better to remove the sensors from the map that reach 100 percent and don't access the items straight forward in the `update` function. Do you initially know which sensors to track? Please consider to add such details to your question! Thanks :)